# Qual a diferença entre operadores '==' e '===' em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre os dois operadores que seriam:

**(1):** `==`

**(2):** `===`

Se possível, também gostaria de entender o neste caso o uso dos operadores opostos deles:

**(3):** `!=`

**(4):** `!==`

**Qual seria a diferença entre os operadores:**

**1:**

```js
if (foo == "foo")
```

**2:**

```js
if (foo === "foo")
```

**E qual seria a diferença entre os operadores opostos:**

**3:**

```js
if (foo !== "foo")
```

**4:**

```js
if (foo != "foo")
```

Alguém poderia me informar?

Comment: A pergunta é diferente, pois o OP está perguntando porque em um caso retorna falso e outro verdadeiro, mas não voltado ao significado real dos operadores, que é o que eu desejo saber.

Comment: @PauloRoberto A resposta é a mesma, eu considero sim duplicata.

Comment: Ok, você pode considerar uma duplicata, porém, a pergunta é diferente, e a Resposta que eu necessito não está encontrada nas respostas na sua "duplicata"

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas

Comment: @bigown ok, logom esta é uma duplicata similar, diferente da exata, por isso a questão deve permanecer aberta.

Comment: Parece que a maioria discorda. Ninguém nem cogita reabrir.

Comment: Eu editei a outra pergunta para ficar um pouco mais genérica. Por que você acha que as respostas de lá não te atendem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A diferença é que no caso de se utilizar `==` haverá uma coerção do valor para que ambos os lados da expressão tenham o mesmo tipo.

No caso do `===` não haverá coerção e por isso o código abaixo dará falso:

```
if(1 === '1')
    console.log('igual');
else
   console.log('diferente');//Esta será a resposta
```

Já se utilizarmos somente `==` haverá uma coerção para que ambos sejam o mesmo tipo e dará igual.

```
if(1 == '1')
    console.log('igual');//Esta será a resposta
else
   console.log('diferente');
```

Outro exemplo:

```
if(0 == '')
    console.log('igual');//Esta será a resposta
else
   console.log('diferente');
```

No caso `''` é considerado um valor `falsey`, que pode ser considerado falso mesmo não tendo o valor `false`.

Já no caso abaixo é dada a mensagem correta, que são diferentes:

```
if(0 === '')
    console.log('igual');
else
   console.log('diferente');//Esta será a resposta
```

**Editado**

Seguem alguns outros valores que podem resultar em casos estranhos na comparação lógica em `javascript`:

Dão falso:

```
0
''
' '
null
undefined
NaN
```

Comment: Gostaria de uma explicação mais especifica, você tem este conhecimento? Ficaria grato em marcar a questão como correta se você especificar.

Comment: Obrigado, eu gostaria de saber tambem uma coisa se possível: quando utilizando `===` ele compara as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo ? Tipo e Valor? no caso de `0 === ''` o javascript entende `''` como `false` e `0` como `false`. Se eu utilizasse `==` ele tambem entenderia da mesma forma?

Comment: Na verdade se usar o `===` ele vai fazer o que seria mais óbvio para a minha mãe :) . Dizer que são diferentes. Imagine você testando se uma variável é `false`. Se utilizar `===` não dará problema mas `'' == false` dirá que é verdadeiro. Existem vários valores em `javascript` que causam essa confusão.

Comment: Ótima explicação essa do "óbvio para a minha mãe", significa o puro entendimento aos olhos de que é diferente, já o `===` prevê uma verificação mais interna, de Tipagem, perfeito.

Comment: Caramba! Essa do `' '` me pegou de surpresa: `if ( ' ' )` considera `' '` como verdadeiro, mas `if ( ' ' == false )` considera `' '` como falso!

Answer (score 6):

`==` faz comparação somente de valor

`===` faz comparação de valor e de tipo

```
if (1 == "1") // retorna true
if (1 === "1") // retorna false
```

Mesma coisa com `=!` e `==!` só que o comando é negação, retorna true se o valor for diferente e/ou o tipo também for diferente.

```
if (1 != "1") // retorna false
if (1 !== "1") // retorna true
```

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é que é verificada o tipo do valor.

Ex:

```
var foo = "10";

console.log(foo == "10"); //true
console.log(foo === 10); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` testa se é igual
`===` testa se é igual e do mesmo tipo

Comment: O teste `0 == ''` dará verdadeiro. Tipos diferentes e valores diferentes.

Comment: o JS considera 0 = ''. testando 1 == '1' retorna true. testando 1 === '1' retorna false. o primeiro testa valor, o segundo testa valor e tipo.

Comment: No meu comentário anterior deu verdadeiro porque o valor é igual ou porque o tipo é igual? Nenhum dos dois, mesmo assim deu verdadeiro.

Comment: @VitorCanova JS considera `0` e `''` como "falsy". `if (0), if (''), if (undefined), if (false)` dão todos na mesma. Muita gente não gosta, mas sim, else são os mesmos (para JS usando coerção)

Comment: @JuanMendes Sim, vou adicionar na minha resposta os `falsey` e `truthy` que eu conheço.