# Qual a diferença entre == e === numa condição?

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre `==` e `===` numa condição, por exemplo:

```
if($string === $string2)
```

e

```
if($string == $string2)
```

Comment: Jorge, acredito que já tenha uma resposta em outra pergunta que não necessariamente seja considerada duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69576/8493

Comment: estará relacionada? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3186/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-operadores-e-em-javascript

Comment: @CesarMiguel essa é em JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O operador `==` apenas verifica se os valores de esquerda e direita são iguais. Já o operador `===`, verifica se os valores de esquerda e direita são iguais, e também verifica para ver se eles são do mesmo tipo de variável.

```
$a == $b    Igual      TRUE se $a é igual a $b.
$a === $b   Idêntico   TRUE se $a é igual a $b, e eles são do mesmo tipo. (introduced in PHP 4)
```

Referência:
[Essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals); 
[Comparação na documentação](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)