# Como diferenciar "001" de "1" no PHP?

Tags: php, operadores

Se eu comparar 001 e 1 no PHP, dá um resultado que os números são idênticos! De fato parece que é! Como faço pra diferenciar 1 de 001, tratar cada um como se fosse diferente?

Comment: mesmo com `===`?

Comment: Ivan, uma duvida importante, seria `$foo = "001";` ou seria `$foo = 001;`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alguma coisa me diz que já existe resposta para isto mas como a busca não retorna nada, vai:

A comparação acaba sendo feita por coerção e ambos são convertidos para número, portanto 1 é igual a 1. Para garantir que a comparação seja correta, tem que comparar com o operador que não faz coerção, e ele é o `===` (idêntico). Na verdade quase sempre deve usar este operador e não o `==` (igual). Este operador é problemático por não considerar o tipo de dado trazendo resultados inesperados.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/cvN81S). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hwivcjxt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Comparing.php).

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Simples, mas interessante! Uma coisa que esqueci de adicionar a pergunta! Eu to fazendo a comparação no banco de dados! Uso o mysql para isso. To tentando comparar a variável preenchida com o que está registrado no BD. Tentei usar o "===" mas esse operador não é aceito!

Comment: Apesar de ser um contexto diferente da pergunta original, coloque na pergunta como está fazendo e eu tento adaptar a resposta. Se está usando no SQL, aí é outra coisa mesmo, aí a pergunta nem é sobre PHP.

Comment: essa [Qual a diferença entre == e === numa condição?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73021/91) ?