# Diferença dos comparadores no php

Tags: php

Galera qual a diferença dos seguinte códigos no php?

```
 if ($resultado_barganha->tipo === "t") { }
```

E:

```
if ($resultado_barganha->tipo == "t") { }
```

Pelo o que eu notei eles fazem a mesma coisa. Porém netbeans recomenda o === porque?

Comment: Parece duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73021/91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**==** verifica se as condições que foram colocadas a comparação são iguais, não importa o tipo, por exemplo

```
if(true == true) // Verdadeiro
if(true == 1) // Verdadeiro
```

**===** ele faz a verificação se as condições são iguais e também verifica o tipo, ou seja, tanto a informação quanto o tipo tem que ser iguais, por exemplo

```
if(true === true) // Verdadeiro
if(true === 1) //Falso
if(1 == 1) //Verdadeiro
```

Retorna falso pois 1 é inteiro e true não é do tipo inteiro e sim booleano

Answer (score 1):

Quando se utiliza == apenas é verificado se os dois valores são iguais.

Mas quando você utiliza === é verificado se os dois valores são iguais e caso não exista informação ele será setado como "t", nunca utilizei com uma string, geralmente utilizo para fazer por exemplo:

if ($resultado_barganha->tipo === false) { }

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentção:

```
$a == $b    Igual   Verdadeiro (TRUE) se $a é igual a $b.

$a === $b   Idêntico    Verdadeiro (TRUE) se $a é igual a $b, e eles são do mesmo tipo.
```

Não há explicação melhor que isso, pelo menos eu acho.

[Referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)