# Como consertar essa função, se eu digito algo aparece a mesma coisa de quando nao digito nada

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Atividade 02</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

CPF <font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15" onsubmit="validar(this)">
<form action="tst.html" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validar();">
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validar () {
    if (validar=="") {
        alert("Todos os campos foram preenchidos.");
        return true;
} else {
        alert("*Campo obrigatório")
        return false;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Opa, se você quer apenas obrigar o usuário a digitar algo no campo você pode usar required no campo que você quer que seja obrigatório, quando ele tentar submeter o formulário aparece a mensagem de obrigatoriedade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Atividade 02</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="tst.html" name="form1" method="post">
            CPF <font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15"required>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obs: sempre ponha seus campos dentro de form como está acima.

Se você quer fazer a validação com JavaScript você pode fazer assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Atividade 02</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
            function validar(event)
            {
                var cpf = document.getElementById("CPF").value;
                if(cpf === "")
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert("Campo obrigatório");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Tudo certo!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="tst.html" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="validar(event);">
            CPF <font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15">
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`event.preventDefault();` vai impedir que o formulário seja submetido;

`var cpf = document.getElementById("CPF").value;` pega o valor que está no campo cpf e logo abaixo compara se está vazio ou não.

Para comparar strings aqui use `===` e não `==` (para uma explicação concreta sobre isso, [olhe essa pergunta e as respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3186/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-operadores-e-em-javascript)).

Espero ter contribuído, até.

Answer (score 1):

Como ficou:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Atividade 02</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
CPF: <font color="red">*</font><input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15">
<input type="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="beforeSubmit();">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function beforeSubmit(){
    var cpf = document.getElementById('CPF').value;
    if (cpf != "") {
        alert("Todos os campos foram preenchidos.");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("*Campo obrigatório")
        return false;
    }
   document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Qualquer dúvida só chamar, espero que tenha ajudado. Bons estudos.

Answer (score 1):

**1º** onsubmit é no formulário, não no objeto, existe varias formas de enviar o dado de um elemento, quando não existe mais de um elemento com o mesmo nome, chamado pelo `nomeobjeto.value` é mais eficiente que colocar `getElementById, getElementByName, getElementByTagName`.

**2º** Quando se vai usar formulário, recomenda-se colocar todos elementos enviados dentro do mesmo. Embora a mesma ação se usar ajax não precisa de formulário.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Atividade 02</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

CPF <font color="red">*</font>
<form action="tst.html" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(CPF.value);">
<input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15">
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validar (valida) {
    if (valida!="") {
        alert("Todos os campos foram preenchidos.");
        return true;
} else {
        alert("*Campo obrigatório")
        return false;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Obs.:** *Acima está o mesmo código com a correção de sintaxe, preservando sua sintaxe, vale destacar que tanto objetos como variáveis, podem retornar outros tipos de saída quando vazios, no exemplo acima um `[vazio] ("")` resolve, mas ele poderia retornar um `NULL, undefined, NaN`, é sempre importante quando executar uma função testa-la em vários Navegadores para evitar esse tipo de incidente, o mesmo ocorre em alguns casos no IE, mas não no Firefox, assim como em outros.*

**Uma dica, valide como númerico e com o numero de caracteres para evitar entrada de texto.**

```
CPF <font color="red">*</font>
<form action="tst.html" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(CPF.value);">
<input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF" size="15">
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"/>
<script>
    function validar (valida) {
    if (valida.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')!="" && valida.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').length==11) {
        alert("Todos os campos foram preenchidos.");
        return true;
} else {
        alert("*Campo obrigatório")
        return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: A expressão regular **[^0-9]** remove texto, permitindo apenas numero na hora de validar, e o atributo **length** conta o numero de caracteres, sempre que for validar itens aplique o **length** fora da validação.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo de validação de mais de um campo http://jsfiddle.net/gf22aaLc/